# If $X$ is a Banach space any capable conditions to make sure that $X$ is also Hilbert?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and suppose that $X$ is **isometric** with a Hilbert space.Is it true to say that $X$ is also a Hilbert space?If I assume that $X$ is **isomorphic** with a Hilbert space is it still true?

Comment: The answer to the first question is clearly yes.  In the second question question what is "isomorphic"?

Comment: In a Hilbert space, the polarization identity gives the inner product as a function of the norm. In order to check that the Banach space is Hilbert, the only thing to do is to check that this expression is a bilinear (or sesquilinear) form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES for the first question, and NO for the second. If $T$ is an isometry from $X$ and $Y$ then $ \langle Tx, Ty \rangle=\langle x, y \rangle$ gives an inner product on $Y$ which makes it a Hilbert space.  $\mathbb R^{2}$ with any norm  is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2}$ with the Euclidean norm . Take the norm $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|$ for a counter-example to  the second statement. I leave it to you to verify that this norm does not satisfy Parallelogram Law which means that the space is not an inner product space. For Parallelogram Law see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Comment: $R^2$ with the || || norm is not Hilbert because the norm does not satisfies the rectangle rule(norm does not come from inner product)??

Comment: @GeorgeGiatilis I have added more details.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time!